# query for column that are within a variable + or 1 of another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has 2 columns, and I am trying to determine a way to select the records where the two columns are CLOSE to one another. Maybe based on standard deviation if i can think about how to do that.  But for now, this is what my table looks like:

```
ID| PCT | RETURN
1 | 20  |  1.20
2 | 15  |  0.90
3 | 0   |  3.00
```

The values in the pct field is a percent number (for example 20%).  The value in the return field is a not fully calculated % number (so its supposed to be 20% above what the initial value was).  The query I am working with so far is this:

```
select * from TABLE1 where ((pct = ((return - 1)* 100)));
```

What I'd like to end up with are the rows where both are within a set value of each other.  For example If they are within 5 points of each other, then the row would be returned and the output would be:

```
ID| PCT | RETURN
1 | 20  |  1.20
2 | 15  |  0.90
```

In the above, ID 1 should work out to be PCT = 20 and Return = 20, and ID 2, is PCT = 15 and RETURN = 10.  Because it was within 5 points of each other, it was returned.

ID 3 was not returned because 0 and 200 are way above the 5 point threshold.

Is there any way to set a variable that would return a +- 5 when comparing the two values from the above attributes?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

RexTester [Example:](https://rextester.com/MHG52435)

Use Lead() over (Order by PCT) to look ahead and LAG() to look back to the next row do the math and evaluate results...

```
WITH CTE (ID, PCT , RETURN) as (
SELECT 1 , 20  ,  1.20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 15  ,  0.90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 0   ,  3.00 FROM DUAL),
CTE2 as (SELECT A.*, LEAD(PCT) Over (ORDER BY PCT) LEADPCT, LAG(PCT) Over (order by PCT) LAGPCT
         FROM CTE A)

SELECT * FROM CTE2
WHERE LEADPCT-PCT <=5 OR PCT-LAGPCT <=5
Order by ID
```

Giving us:

```
+----+----+-----+--------+---------+--------+
|    | ID | PCT | RETURN | LEADPCT | LAGPCT |
+----+----+-----+--------+---------+--------+
|  1 |  1 |  20 |   1,20 | NULL    |     15 |
|  2 |  2 |  15 |   0,90 | 20      |      0 |
+----+----+-----+--------+---------+--------+
```

or use the return value instead of PCT... just depends on what you're after.  But maybe I don't fully understand the question..

Comment: I'm trying to compare the 2 columns with each other, and only return the rows where pct and return are within 5 of each other.  The only stipulation is that the return number is more 'raw' and thats why i do that calculation on it to try to get it up to a true percent.